# How would I complete my match function/method? I need to finish this for loop

Tags: java

Count the number of words in a sentence that contain exactly two vowels
between a pair of “z” characters with no "z" between them. There may be multiple spaces between words, and a letter may be upper or lower case. Show the number of words in each sentence that match the pattern.

I have the following function code so far the for loop, I need to know how to complete it. please help me.

Here are some test cases:

```
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Sentence                                  | Matching words |
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
| a ZOO animal is a Zebraz                  | 1              |
| a ZOoZ animal is a Zebraz                 | 2              |
| the zebrazska goozed at the barking zEAlz | 2              |
| azoooza azoo ZORROrroozaster azurez       | 1              |
| nothing much here                         | 0              |
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Here's my code so far:

```
private boolean matches(String word)
{
    int Vowels = 3;
    for (int i=3; i<word.length(); ++i) {
        if (word.charAt(i)=='z' )
        {

            return true;
        } else {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: pls add a example to understand

Comment: What made you start your loop from 3?

Comment: Nothing else between them either - `zv1v2z` for example or any number of characters other than z with exactly 2 vowels?

Comment: yes there can be numbers and letters but they are not counted.

Comment: Can you use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Comment: why do you have an answer or are you simply asking questions??

Comment: Please provide some example so that it make us easy to understand.

Comment: Who keeps downvoting?? Why?

Comment: I just down voted for the attitude I'm detecting. If you don't want to answer questions which will help you get help, then why ask? - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about it:

```
static int countVowels(String atom)
{
  int counter = 0;

  for (int i = 0, l = atom.length(); i < l; i++) {
    char c = atom.charAt(i);

    if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c) != -1) {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  return counter;
}

static int countMatches(String word)
{
  int count = 0;

  int last_z = -1;

  for (int i = 0, l = word.length(); i < l; i++) {
    char c = word.charAt(i);

    if ((c == 'z') || (c == 'Z')) {
      if (last_z != -1) {
        if (countVowels(word.substring(last_z, (i + 1))) == 2) {
          count++;
        }
      }

      last_z = i;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int total = 0;

  {
    StringTokenizer st = (new StringTokenizer(args[0]));

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      total += countMatches(st.nextToken());
    }
  }

  System.out.println(total);
}
```